# how to tell if a javascript variable is a function

Tags: javascript, typeof

I need to loop over the properties of a javascript object.  How can I tell if a property is a function or just a value?

```
var model =
{
    propertyA: 123,
    propertyB: function () { return 456; }
};

for (var property in model)
{
    var value;
    if(model[property] is function) //how can I tell if it is a function???
        value = model[property]();
    else 
        value = model[property];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a javascript variable is function type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof):

```
if (typeof model[property] == 'function') ...
```

*Also, note that you should be sure that the properties you are iterating are part of this object, and not inherited as a public property on the prototype of some other object up the inheritance chain:*

```
for (var property in model){
  if (!model.hasOwnProperty(property)) continue;
  ...
}
```

Comment: that is only reliable if the property is a native function. If it is a host object, you can get anything, even an error.

Comment: @RobG Oh? `typeof (new XMLHttpRequest).getAllResponseHeaders` returns `"function"` for me on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. Is this an IE issue, or is there a different host object or method you're thinking of? (It's not that I doubt you, I'm just looking for an example.)

Answer (score 6):

Following might be useful to you, I think.

[How can I check if a javascript variable is function type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type)

BTW, I am using following to check for the function.

```
    // Test data
    var f1 = function () { alert("test"); }
    var o1 = { Name: "Object_1" };
    F_est = function () { };
    var o2 = new F_est();

    // Results
    alert(f1 instanceof Function); // true
    alert(o1 instanceof Function); // false
    alert(o2 instanceof Function); // false
```

Comment: Though unlikely, note that this will fail if you are testing a function value that came from another window frame (as each frame has its own `Function` root).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to check if a JavaScript variable is a function:

```
var model =
{
    propertyA: 123,
    propertyB: function () { return 456; }
};

for (var property in model)
{
    var value;
    if(typeof model[property] == 'function') // Like so!
    else 
        value = model[property];
}
```

Comment: Consider calling providing a little bit of written explanation for what you did apart from just the // Like so! comment.  Maybe preface your code with a suggestion to "use the _typeof_ operator to determine the type of the property's value."