# How to check if a knockout observable exists?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Say I have a json of observables :

```
self.name = ko.observable('Arnab');
self.surname= ko.observale('Bhagabati')

var person = {
  name:ko.observable('Arnab'),
  lastName= ko.observale('Bhagabati')
}
```

I can access the name of person by `console.log(person.name());`

How do I check whether my `person` has a knockout observable property called, say `salary`?

```
if (typeof person.salary() !== 'undefined')
```

gives `params.salary is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

> How do I check whether my person **has a knockout observable property** called, say salary?

<sub>*(emphasis mine)*</sub>

If you use a check along the lines of `if (ko.unwrap(person.salary))`, like the other answers suggest, you're basically checking if there's a defined `salary` property.

I.e.:

```
person = { salary: undefined };
person = { };
person = { salary: ko.observable() };
```

Will all return `true` for `typeof ko.unwrap(person.salary) === "undefined"`

If I take what you wrote literally, this doesn't answer whether the 'person' object has an observable property called `salary`.

To answer this question, you'll need `ko.isObservable`:

```js
var persons = [
  [{ }, "{ }"],
  [{ salary: undefined }, "{ salary: undefined }" ],
  [{ salary: ko.observable() }, "{ salary: ko.observable()" ]
]

var check1 = person => typeof ko.unwrap(person.salary) === "undefined";
var check2 = person => ko.isObservable(person.salary);

console.log(check1.toString());
persons.forEach(([p, c]) => console.log(c, "->", check1(p)));

console.log(check2.toString());
persons.forEach(([p, c]) => console.log(c, "->", check2(p)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

It might be that I took your question too literally, and all you need is `ko.unwrap`, but I felt I had to share the difference

Answer (score 4):

observables are functions. If there is no `salary` property, `person.salary()` will throw an exception.

So you can use:

```
if (typeof ko.unwrap(person.salary) !== 'undefined')
{

}
```

`unwrap` returns the value of the property, irrespective of whether it's observable or not.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9624401/3082296) on more info

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, `!=` checks for both `null` and `undefined`:

```
if (person.salary != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = ko.unwrap(person.salary);
```

and

```
console.log(ko.unwrap(person.salary));
```

will work no matter whether `person.salary` is observable or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution, just see if the object type is a function, and then add a couple of checks for knockout specific functions to exist in it.  This is handy to use in ko.computed, when you are pretty dern sure that the observable are GOING to be there, but aren't yet.

```
var isKoObservable = function(obs) {
  var retVal = false;
  if (typeof obs === "function") {
    if (typeof obs.subscribe === "function" && typeof obs.notifySubscribers === "function") {
      // its HIGHLY likely to be an observable or observableArray
      retVal = true; 
    }
  }

  return retVal;
}
```

See this SO answer for details:
[how to tell if a javascript variable is a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861763/how-to-tell-if-a-javascript-variable-is-a-function)